# How can i add certain flags to my Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

i built an activity that can launch itself when i hit a certain button-combination on my locked screen. I also managed to keep the activity running despite pressing the powerButton two times --> screen off and screen on --> activity is still running and keyguard still retired from duty. This is done by adding flags in the onCreate()-method of my activity.

```
 i.e. getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Now i want to achieve the same with the Intent.ACTION_CALL. But the problem is that i can't override any method of that intent as it seems to be exclusively run by android. Also, adding flags to the intent before i hit startActivity doesn't work as i can't use the necessary flags here.

Does anyone have an idea how i can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct, you want to make another activity, you starting with Intent.ACTION_CALL action, to add some flags to it's window.

It's not possible on Android. It means another app should give everyone rights to control itself in order to do this.

You can only add flags to Intent for controlling new activity start and tasking options. 
See [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT), you can use flags, that starts with FLAG_ACTIVITY

Comment: it is the same conclusion i came to, i was just hoping that someone proofs me wrong :)

Comment: Will see :) But I can hardly believe this, because if system would work as you mentioned - it's a serious security issue.

Comment: well, my other activity works fine this way. Just the intent refuses to work. I will try checking out if I can build an activity that does the calling. me boss wants to see results ;)

Comment: As for calling activity, not far time ago I've spent a lot of time to research this problem and short answer - you can actually make only dialer activity, and rewriting phone application is possible only through developing your custom firmware for each device, you need to support and make users to flash it, so, in general meaning it's impossible :)

Comment: i decided that i will try to build a service that handles the dismissing of the keyguard and fetching the call from the background once it re-enters the homescreen. Alternatively i will check if i can handle it with destroying the intent when screen turns off and starting a new intent when reching the homescreen.